# Unable to start Logstash (7.1.1) on Windows 2012 R2

Tags: java

I am unable to start Logstash (7.1.1) on Windows 2012 R2. When I run this simple command:

```
logstash -e "input { stdin { } } output { stdout {} }"
```

To check whether Logstash is working or not, I am getting below error:

```
warning: ignoring JAVA_OPTS= -Xms1g -Xmx1g -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitia
tingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -Djava.awt.headless=
true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djruby.compile.invokedynamic=true -Djruby.jit.thresh
old=0 -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/urandom ; pa
ss JVM parameters via LS_JAVA_OPTS
```

Even logs are not being created.

Elasticsearch and Kibana are working fine.

Note - When I have run same Logstash (7.1.1) in Windows 7, it is working fine. I am using same Java version (`jdk1.8.0_92`) for both machines.

Comment: Could be a memory leak issue as indicated by the `+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` text in that error. I would recommend the basic “Reboot the machine and try again…” method.